# How to get value of returned element in Selenium Python execute_script?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I using Selenium Python bindings to find some elements.
in some place i need to use execute_script method.
Hot to get returned values from executing this script?

So i put:

```
browser = driver.Chrome() #for example
script = "document.getElementById('element')"
browser.execute_script(script)
```

How to receive values into python log or variable from that script? Like element`s ID, text, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem where **selenium** was not able to find some element but the **JavaScript console** on chrome found it.

So I tried adding a "**return**" string in the execute script method, which in your case would be:

```
browser = driver.Chrome()
myElement = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementById('element_id')")
```

You can also do different operations like you do with **Selenium Web-elements**.

Example:

```
browser = driver.Chrome()
elementList = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('element_class_name')")
elementList[0].click() # Clicks the first element from list
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

From the js [doc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html) (python api can be found there)

> If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains a
>   return statement), then the following steps will be taken for
>   resolving this functions return value: 
>    - For a HTML element, the value will resolve to a webdriver. WebElement
>    - Null and undefined return values will resolve to null
>    - Booleans, numbers, and strings will resolve as is  Functions will resolve to
>      their string representation 
>    - For arrays and objects, each member item
>      will be converted according to the rules above

P.S. Why you need to find element using executeScript?

Comment: Because it is my task :)
So, ok:
I have variable called `returned_js`
And i need to assign some value of JavaScript return to this var.